# accept post data in asp and insert into sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, post

I just re did my question and added a few other scripts needed to pull everything together

This is the small script I am using to receive the post and push the data into the SQL Server (2008 if that matters):
UPDATE 2 after suggestions:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<script runat="server">
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Integrated Security=false;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DOMAIN_NAME;UserID=user;Password=password")
myConn.Open()
Dim sqlstring As String = " INSERT INTO sean.local (etype, latitude, longtitude, phone) VALUES ('" + Request.Form("type") + "','" + Request.Form("latitude") + "','" + Request.Form("longtitude") + "','" + Request.Form("phone") + "')"
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
myConn.Close()
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, True)
Response.Write("1 record added")
End Sub
</script>
```

here is my create table script

```
CREATE TABLE local
(
P_Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
etype varchar(255) NOT NULL,
latitude varchar(255),
longtitude varchar(255),
phone varchar(255)
)
```

and here is the form I am using to test

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>A Web Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <BR></BR>
 <form action="http://www.mydomain.com/script.asp" method="post">
 <h1>Form Test</h1>
 Phone:<BR></BR><input type="text" name="phone"/>      
 <BR></BR>
 type:<BR></BR><input type="text" name="type"/>
 <BR></BR>
 lat:<BR></BR><input type="text" name="latitude"/>
 <BR></BR>
 lng:<BR></BR><input type="text" name="longtitude"/>
 <BR></BR>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Data"/>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

It might be something small but I really  have no other ideas...thank you.

Comment: "I think I am mixing VB and C# together, I am just tangled and lost," - never heard that one before!

Comment: `Dim varname As Type` should be `Type varname;` with C#.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Don't use string concatenation like that to build your queries.

Comment: I will look into that, I really want to get the basic functionality first and then get sanitization of my data next....do you have any ideas of what im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mostly VB, just switch to it

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Integrated Security=false;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DOMAIN_NAME;UserID=abc;Password=123")
        myConn.Open()
        Dim sqlstring As String = " INSERT INTO sean.local (etype, latitude, longtitude, phone) VALUES ('" + Request.Form("type") + "','" + Request.Form("latitude") + "','" + Request.Form("longtitude") + "','" + Request.Form("phone") + "')"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConn.Close()
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, True)
        Response.Write("1 record added")
    End Sub
</script>
```

If you need it in C#, run it through this: http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Code%20Converter.ashx

Comment: So everything looks ok on the hosting side...I am looking into the SQL server

Answer (score 0):

This will fix several problems in your existing code, including some you don't even know about yet:

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO sean.local (etype, latitude, longtitude, phone) VALUES (@etype, @latitude, @longtitude, @phone)"
    Using myConn As New SqlConnection("Integrated Security=false;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DOMAIN_NAME;UserID=user;Password=password"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

       'I had to make up database types... edit this to use the real types
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@etype", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = Request.Form("type")
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@latitude", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Request.Form("latitude")
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@longtitude", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Request.Form("longtitude")
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.Varchar, 12).Value = Request.Form("phone")

       myConn.Open()
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, True)

    'This line will never run!
    Response.Write("1 record added")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, I am still receiving the 500 error, I am trying to see if i can get any other feedback from IE or Firefox but I am unable to figure it out